# GIT: Not Tracked files in source tree

Tags: git, github

I have a development branch, which I just checked out from origin. I'm getting more than 2000 files as not tracked, which I am not able to pull or push.

I'm getting error as:

> Following untracked working files will be over written by merge

Can anybody please help me on this?

Comment: what did you do after you checked out?  Did you do a build?  are the untracked files build products?  Where did they come from?  Are they suitable for .gitignore?

Comment: yes i did the build is it the reason ?

Answer (score 2):

This is probably what happened.  You did a build.  That created a lot of untracked files that were products of the build, for instance .o files or the like.  A teammate also did a build and somehow accidentally committed some of these build-product files.  Now his commit overlaps your untracked files, and Git won't let you merge.  There are two steps you need to take.  One is required for your merge: you need to get the untracked files out of the way.  One way to do that is with [`git clean`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean).

```
git clean
```

That removes all untracked files from your working tree, and you will then be able to merge.

But you also don't want this to happen again, and do that you should create a [`.gitignore`](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) file that teaches Git not to worry about build products.  Then find the build product your teammate accidentally committed, and remove it from the project, so that  from that point on it can be ignored.

Comment: Before running `git clean`, run `git clean -n` to see a list of files it will delete to make sure you won't accidentally delete anything you want to keep.